# I am doing a twitter sentiment analysis and only one of the my pulls from twitter is being processed

Tags: twitter, rstudio

R File:

```
# Install and Activate Packages
# install.packages("twitteR", "RCurl", "RJSONIO", "stringr", "ROAuth")

library(twitteR)
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
library(stringr)
library(ROAuth)
library(plyr)

# Declare Twitter API Credentials
api_key <- "MLTS91hQlJaPOPpdDTOeNAaHU" # From dev.twitter.com
api_secret <- "bUdEdspvjOfQ192INw48K84lZulRBLgOMqu0ukr6FRyysaW95f" # From dev.twitter.com
token <- "336148817-VQgCSg9KDng71zNOpsbkFhHSPImaO1nFvJTd4HmK" # From dev.twitter.com
token_secret <- "WAGmLbICos6M2QQaWJWGyhKPKCPqyE5pVV1FPNLMg5tkI" # From dev.twitter.com

# Create Twitter Connection
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, token, token_secret)

delta.tweets = searchTwitter('@delta', n=1500)
#delta.tweets
americanair.tweets = searchTwitter('@americanair', n=1500)
#americanair.tweets
#JetBlueAirlines.tweets = searchTwitter('@jetblueairlines', n=1500)
SouthwestAir.tweets = searchTwitter('@SouthwestAir', n=1500)
united.tweets = searchTwitter('@united', n=1500)
USAirways.tweets = searchTwitter('@USAirways', n=1500)

#loading opinion lexicon
setwd('C:/Users/SRC/Downloads')
hu.liu.pos <- scan('positive-words.txt',
                    what='character', comment.char=';')
hu.liu.neg = scan('negative-words.txt',
                    what='character', comment.char=';')
pos.words = c(hu.liu.pos, 'upgrade')
neg.words = c(hu.liu.neg, 'wtf', 'wait',
                'waiting', 'epicfail', 'mechanical')
hu.liu.pos
hu.liu.neg

#Sentiment analysis code
score.sentiment = function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words, .progress='none')
{
  require(plyr)
  require(stringr)
  # we got a vector of sentences. plyr will handle a list or a vector as an "l" for us
  # we want a simple array of scores back, so we use "l" + "a" + "ply" = laply:
  scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words) {

    # clean up sentences with R's regex-driven global substitute, gsub():
    sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence)
    sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence)
    sentence = gsub('\\d+', '', sentence)
    # and convert to lower case:
    sentence = tolower(sentence)
    # split into words. str_split is in the stringr package
    word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+')
    # sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much
    words = unlist(word.list)
    # compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms
    pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)
    neg.matches = match(words, neg.words)
    # match() returns the position of the matched term or NA
    # we just want a TRUE/FALSE:
    pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)
    neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)
    # and conveniently enough, TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():
    score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)
    return(score)
  }, pos.words, neg.words, .progress=.progress )
  scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)
  return(scores.df)
}


delta.scores = score.sentiment(delta.text, pos.words,
                               neg.words, .progress='text')

hist(delta.scores$score)

americainair.scores = score.sentiment(americanair.text, pos.words,
                               neg.words, .progress='text')

Southwestair.scores = score.sentiment(Southwestair.text, pos.words,
                               neg.words, .progress='text')

united.scores = score.sentiment(united.text, pos.words,
                               neg.words, .progress='text')

USAirways.scores = score.sentiment(USAirways.text, pos.words,
                               neg.words, .progress='text')
```

RStudio Console:

```
> delta.scores = score.sentiment(delta.text, pos.words,
+ neg.words, .progress='text')
  |======================================================================================================| 100%
> hist(delta.scores$score)
> americainair.scores = score.sentiment(americanair.text, pos.words,
+ neg.words, .progress='text')
```

Show Traceback

Rerun with Debug
Error in inherits(.data, "split") : object 'americanair.text' not found > Southwestair.scores = score.sentiment(Southwestair.text, pos.words,
    + neg.words, .progress='text')

Show Traceback

Rerun with Debug
 Error in inherits(.data, "split") : object 'Southwestair.text' not found > united.scores = score.sentiment(united.text, pos.words,
+ neg.words, .progress='text')
 Show Traceback

Rerun with Debug
 Error in inherits(.data, "split") : object 'united.text' not found > USAirways.scores = score.sentiment(USAirways.text, pos.words,
+ neg.words, .progress='text')
 Show Traceback

Rerun with Debug
 Error in inherits(.data, "split") : object 'USAirways.text' not found

Comment: The positive/negative-opinion lexicons can be downloaded here: https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, silly mistake with variable font case